# Chatbase Login Integration

Tags: integration, chatbot, chatbase

I integrated my application with the chatbase, but I would like my clients to have direct access to their email directly, as if it were a single step.
When I click a button in my application, it is directed to the logged-in chatbase screen.
Today I can only get it to the login screen, where it is still necessary to put the password to go to the dashboard, not logging directly into the application.

Is this possible? if yes, is there any kind of quickstart?

I followed the tutorial below to get to the login area, remembering that I use node.js

https://scotch.io/tutorials/easy-node-authentication-google

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your interest in Chatbase. There is currently no support for OAuth logins. Please see our recommended steps for third party integrations below:

1. Have the user open a Chatbase account with a Google linked email address
2. Have the user create a Bot in order to obtain the API key
3. Have the user integrate their analytics on your platform by providing the API key
4. Send the messages from their bot to their Chatbase API
5. Provide the user deeplinks to the Chatbase reports from within your UI